# Парсинг элементов через DomCrawler

Tags: php, html, парсер, dom

На странице имеется несколько элементов с таким набором классов. Мне необходимо распарсить все и из каждого элемента вытянуть ссылку. Вот код **HTML** :

```
<a class="Place__headerLink Place__title
            Link Link--shade-80 h5 small Place--lineClamping" href="https://club-drozdy.relax.by/" target="_blank" title="Drozdy Club" data-reactid=".yfuzkhv2j8.5.0.0.1.0.0.$10336959.2.1.0.0.0.0">Drozdy Club</a>
```

Вот **PHP** код парсера :

```
$crawler->filter('a.Place__title.Link.Link--shade-80.h5.small.Place--lineClamping')->attr('href');
        foreach ($list as $item){
            var_dump($item);
        }
```

Получаю ошибку `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: по какому классу?, куда вы опять код потеряли? :) никто не скажет в чем ошибка, если не увидит код

Comment: `class="Place__headerLink Place__title
            Link Link--shade-80 h5 small Place--lineClamping" ` ну, по этим классам. Даже, если я например пытаюсь вывести `$list = $crawler->filter('class.Place__title Link Link--shade-80 h5 small Place--lineClamping')->first()` - получаю ошибку `The current node list is empty.` А вообще, мне нужно вывести  все элементы с указанным набором классов.

Comment: в таком виде это  у вас вложенное дерево классов. ваш селектор, наверное, должен быть `a.Place__title.Link` и так далее, без пробелов и точка перед именем класса, ибо пробел - вложенность

Comment: Действительно, на счёт точек вы попали прямо в точку) А как мне получить все записи с таким набором классов на странице? Я пытаюсь что-то вроде этого делать `$list = $crawler->filter('a.Place__title.Link.Link--shade-80.h5.small.Place--lineClamping');
        foreach ($list as $item){
            echo $item->attr('href');
        }`  и получаю ошибки. Я так понимаю, мне результат фильтра нужно представить в виде массива? А потом перебирать? Но как?)

Comment: Я эту симфонию в глаза не видел, страницу с кравлером глянул пока смотрел сериал, счас у нас уже 3 ночи и я в кровати с телефоном, так что с утра вам кто нить да поможет :D с виду все норм, напишите что за ошибки. И да, можно редактировать вопрос, добавляя туда сведения, кнопка [edit]

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Подредактировал вопрос

Comment: что-то у вас код в комментарии и в вопросе несколько различался :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему использованием `extract()`, вместо `attr()`. 
Вот код :

```
 $list = $crawler->filter('a.Place__title.Link.Link--shade-80.h5.small.Place--lineClamping')->extract('href');

    print_r($list);
```